# Calculating execution time

Tags: processor

I am trying to find out how long it takes to execute 10,000 RISC instructions with 4 bytes from a processor that is 2GHz and another that is 4GHz, I only need the very basics of a formula

I have tried 10,000 x 4 =  40,000 / 2x10^9 and 40,000 / 4x10^9

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a correct way to calculate this. There are a number of dependencies and complexities:

1. What type of instructions are included? Instructions cycle counts can vary from 1 cycle to 20-30 cycles per instructions.  How many of these instructions can be dispatched at once?
2. What is the memory access pattern and how is the CPU memory access designed?  How effective will caching/pre-fetching be (and does the CPU support)?
3. Are there many branches?  How predictable are those branches and how many are within the critical portion of the code? What is the cost of a miss-predict?
   and more.

Fundamentally the question you are asking isn't easily solvable and absolutely depends on the code to be run.

Generally speaking, code execution does not scale linearly so it is unlikely that for anything non-trivial that a 4GHz processor will be twice as fast as a 2GHz processor.